# Upcasting with vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working with my code and I faced this problem. I want to put 3 different classes data in single vector, so I created base class vector. It look like this :

```
std::vector <Video*> vid_list;
```

When I read the file I push data in this vector using one of the derived class constructors like that :

```
vid_list.push_back(new Official_Music_Video(video_title, video_time,
                Date(y,m,d), num_of_views));
```

so I want to display this data on the screen, but my base class only got methods for

```
std::string title;
double time;
Date date_of_release;
```

but not for `int number_of_views`. I heard that if I wanna use derived class getter method I have to use upcasting so I tried to make this

```
void views (Video& v) {
    v.get_views();
}
```

and then in my display method

```
void Official_Music_Video::display_info(std::vector <Video*>& vid_list){
    Official_Music_Video ofc;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vid_list.size(); i++){
        cout << vid_list[i]->get_title() << " " << vid_list[i]->get_time()
        << " " << vid_list[i]->write_year_to_file() << "-" <<
        vid_list[i]->write_month_to_file() << "-" << vid_list[i]- 
        >write_day_to_file () << endl;
        cout << "This video viewed " << vid_list[i].views(ofc) << " times" 
        << endl;
   } 
}
```

But it's not working. Can you help me understand where I made mistake and what's wrong ?

Comment: No, you want *downcasting* done via `dynamic_cast`

Comment: "But it's not working" - **how** is it not working?

Comment: I would make sure Video is an interface class with virtual destructor. I would make it a vector of smart pointers to Video. If you need number of views, add it to the interface, or the interface may not need any of that info if you make get_display_info the interface function (return a string?).

Comment: `vid_list[i].views(ofc)` For starters, `vid_list[i]` is a pointer, so you should use `->` like you did with other methods. Or is `views` a stand-alone function?

Comment: for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vid_list.size(); i++) {
        Official_Music_Video* ofc = dynamic_cast 
        <Official_Music_Video*>(vid_list[i]);
        if (ofc != nullptr){
            cout << "This video viewed " << vid_list[i].get_views() << " 
            times" << endl;
        }
    }

Comment: @UnholySheep you mean like this ?

Answer (score 0):

If all three of your derived classes have a "number_of_views" method, put it in the base class as well, and problem solved. If not, then your code is nonsensical. What do you expect to happen when you put an "Unofficial_Music_Video" into the vector, and run your loop over it?

If you really need to add per-type behavior to the class, consider what you actually want to accomplish. Do you need users of Video to be able to query "number_of_views", despite the fact that field doesn't exist for all subtypes? Maybe you just want to access a human-readable description of the statistics? If that's the case, it might make the most sense to add a "virtual std::string StatsSummary()" method to Video, and make subclasses implement it as required.

Comment: All 3 classes have different data and I can't just put one into the base class. My program will see which class data is in file line and then read it using different classes display methods.

Comment: As I said: What do you expect your loop to do when an item *doesn't* have a "number_of_views" field? What words would you use to describe what all three sets of behavior have in common? Can you factor out a virtual method that performs *that* into a base class, and override it in each child?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move some of the implementation to the base class or so, but this is something that could help you finding the solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Date // for demo only
{
public:
    Date(int y, int, int m, int d)
        : y(y) , m(m), d(d) {}
    int y;
    int m;
    int d;
};

class Video
{
public:

    virtual std::string get_title() = 0;
    virtual int get_time() = 0;
    virtual int write_year_to_file() = 0;
    virtual int write_month_to_file() = 0;
    virtual int write_day_to_file () = 0;
    virtual ~Video(){}
    virtual void display_info()
    {
        std::cout << get_title()
            << " " << get_time()
            << " " << write_year_to_file()
            << "-" << write_month_to_file()
            << "-" << write_day_to_file ()
            << std::endl;
    }
};


class VideoWithViewCount
    : public Video
{
public:
    virtual int views() = 0;

        virtual void display_info()
    {
        Video::display_info();
        std::cout << "This video viewed " << views() << " times"  << std::endl;
    }

};


class Official_Music_Video : public VideoWithViewCount
{
public:
    Official_Music_Video(std::string _video_title, int _video_time,  Date _date, int _Num_of_views)
        : d(_date)
        , time(_video_time)
        , Num_of_views(_Num_of_views)
        , video_title(_video_title)
    {}

    virtual int get_time() override {return time; };
    virtual int write_year_to_file() override { return d.y; } // better call them get...
    virtual int write_month_to_file() override {return d.m; }
    virtual int write_day_to_file () override { return d.d; }
    virtual int views() override {return Num_of_views; };
private:
    Date d;
    int time;
    int Num_of_views;
    std::string video_title;
};

class Other_Video : public Video
{
public:
    Other_Video(std::string _video_title, int _video_time,  Date _date)
        : d(_date)
        , time(_video_time)
        , video_title(_video_title)
    {}

    virtual int get_time() override {return time; };
    virtual int write_year_to_file() override { return d.y; }
    virtual int write_month_to_file() override {return d.m; }
    virtual int write_day_to_file () override { return d.d; }
private:
    Date d;
    int time;
    std::string video_title;
};

int main(int,char**)
{
    std::vector <Video*> vid_list;
    // could also use unique_ptr or shared_ptr  from #include <memory> in vector as follows:
    // std::vector <unique_ptr<Video> > vid_list;
    // std::vector <shared_ptr<Video> > vid_list;

    // fill video vector
    // vid_list.push_back(new Official_Music_Video(video_title, video_time,  Date(y,m,d), num_of_views));

    for (auto v : vid_list) // when using unique_ptr remember to use "const auto&" instead of "auto"
    {
        v->display_info();
    }

    return 0;
}
```